# how to prevent control disappearing when form's width is decreased?

Tags: c#-4.0, anchor, tablelayout, dock

I want to make a resizable menu on the top of my main Windows form. I added a TableLayoutPanel and set its Dock property to **Top**. There are equal 4 columns on this TableLayoutPanel. I have added a button on every columns and set their Dock property to **Fill**. When I maximize the form, my menu becomes wider and fits to form's width. That is what I want for now. However, when I **decrease**(not minimized) the width of form, buttons started to disappear from the left. I expect to autosize itself when form's width decrease. How can I prevent this? Any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't configure the columns in the TLP correctly.

Comment: @HansPassant columns are on their default value which is: autosize

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this behavior quite quickly in VS2013 targeting the .Net 4.0 framework. It appears as though the last column is the one affected by the autosizing process. I set the columns to be absolute (20 pixels) and then used a dynamic calculation to determine the percentage of the screen that the column should consume. Any time you add/remove a column, you would need to call the `SetColumnSize()` method.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetColumnSize();


    }

    private void SetColumnSize()
    {
        float colPercent = 100 / this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, colPercent));
        }
    }
```